# How to validate dropdown menu in a form using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, validation

I've learned most of my jQuery from tools such as Treehouse and CodeSchool so some of this material might look familiar.

I'm trying to validate a dropdown within a form before the submit button becomes active. However, whenever I make a selection and type something in, the submit button doesn't become active.

Here's an example of what I have right now:

```js
function containsBlanks() {
  var blanks = $('.required').map(function() {
    return $(this).val() === "";
  });
  return $.inArray(true, blanks) != -1;
}

function FilledIn() {
  if (containsBlanks()) {
    $('#submit_btn').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  } else {
    $('#submit_btn').removeAttr('disabled');
  }
}
FilledIn();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<form id="basic_form">
  <select name="lighterColors" id="lighterColors" class="required">
    <option value="">--Select--</option>
    <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="Red">Red</option>
  </select>

  <br>

  <label for="name"></label>
  <input type="text" id="name" class="required">
  <br>
  <input id="submit_btn" type="submit">
</form>
```

I've changed the value of the Select option to any random value but still does not remove the attr from submit_btn. Please help with any suggestions.

Comment: is your function `FilledIn()` running on document.ready. If yes apply on `focus` of element

Comment: Try using change event istead of map - var blanks = $('.required').change(function() {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below plugin can be called like: `$('.requiredSelects').validateSelects('#submit_btn');`

Where `.requiredSelects` is the selector for any elements that must be filled in and `#submit_btn` is the selector for the button that should be disabled unless all fields are filled in.

```js
(function ($) {
    $.fn.validateSelects = function (btn) {
        var elements = this;
        var invalid = 0;
        // make sure to return here so the pulgin is chainable
        return elements.change(function() { // bind to change event 
            invalid = 0;
            elements.each(function() {
                if ($(this).val() === "") invalid++;
            });
            invalid > 0 ? $(btn).attr('disabled', 'disabled') : $(btn).removeAttr('disabled');
        });
    };
}(jQuery));



$('.requiredSelects').validateSelects('#submit_btn');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<form id="basic_form">
    <select name="lighterColors" id="lighterColors" class="requiredSelects">
        <option value="">--Select--</option>
        <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
        <option value="Red">Red</option>
    </select>
    <select name="lighterColors" id="lighterColors" class="requiredSelects">
        <option value="">--Select--</option>
        <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
        <option value="Red">Red</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <label for="name"></label>
    <input type="text" id="name" class="required" />
    <br>
    <input id="submit_btn" type="submit" disabled />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks Delighted. I got it working :-) 
Would it be proper to add the requiredSelects class to the input field as well or would it be better practice to create it's own function and check that each one of those functions returns a true statement in a third function?

Comment: as it's written it would also work for text inputs or textareas, as you surmised, just give them all the same class. Id rename the class to "requiredInputs" or something though.  However, if you're going to be doing a lot of validation, you might want to look into a validation library like http://jqueryvalidation.org/